# AWS API Gateway Error: Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to build an API using a Lambda function in node.js, and I wanted to access the `event` object so that I could use the request body and the path parameters in my API. I have a database in Aurora PostgreSQL and I’m using the API Gateway to invoke the Lambda functions. Here is my code for a simple GET request:

```
console.log('PostgreSQL GET Function');

var pg = require("pg");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var conn = "postgres://URL";
    var client = new pg.Client(conn);
    client.connect();

    var id = event.id;
    console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
    console.log('Connected to PostgreSQL database');
    var query = client.query("SELECT * from USERS;");
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
    });
    
    query.on("end", function (result) {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        console.log(jsonString);
        client.end();
        context.succeed(jsonObj);
    });
};
```

When I tried logging the `event` object into my console, I get an empty object as my result {}.

> 2020-09-29T06:05:34.423Z ... INFO EVENT: {}

So I looked up the documentation and was informed that I had to enable ‘proxy integration’, however having doing so, my API has stopped running and I get an "internal server error” with the error message

`Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses`

Where am I going wrong and how do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change a non-proxy to proxy integration in your API, you **need to modify your lambda code**. The `event` object will be different now and also you need to return a response in a correct format.

The structure of the `event` object is shown in:

- [Input format of a Lambda function for proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format)

The required output from the function is shown in:

- [Output format of a Lambda function for proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)

Also you should inspect CloudWatch Logs for any error messages that you function can produce to help to troubleshoot its failure.